# Archive.org web scraper bot is causing high server loads - how to slow it down?

Tags: apache, web-crawler, rate-limiting, webarchive

Archive .org (waybackmachine) is crawling several sites on my Apache server and crashing them due to very high burst traffic.

I don't want to block their crawler, but I want to rate limit them.  I have contacted their support and their answer was "No, we don't offer a crawl rate - there's nothing we can do about it".

How can I speed rate limit their IPs?

207.241.230.103

207.241.232.92

207.241.230.131

207.241.232.90

207.241.232.89

And it looks as though I am not the only one;

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/207.241.232.90

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/207.241.230.131

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/207.241.230.103

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/207.241.232.92

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/207.241.232.89

Comment: Search for throttling, or rate limitation, there is an Apache module specific to that.  https://serverfault.com/questions/540743/how-to-rate-limit-apache-server-on-ip-basis